# How to parse "It might be possible for a single woman to be accepted as a foster parent"?

Tags: passive-voice, to-infinitive, for

> It might be possible for a single woman to be accepted as a foster
>   parent.

I have two explanations:

(1) (A single woman to be accepted as a foster parent) might be possible. = That a single woman can be accepted as a foster parent might be possible.

(2) For a single woman , to be accepted as a foster parent might be possible.

Comment: What's the difference between these two?

Comment: @CYC I think they refer to 1) as being the concept of any single woman at all being accepted, and 2) as for a specific woman, there might be a possibility. And then, 2) implies 1). I'm leaning towards interpreting this as 2).

Answer (score 2):

The main clause in the sentence is "It might be possible". The word "it" is referring to "a single woman to be accepted as a foster parent". You could rephrase the sentence as "(A single woman being accepted as a foster parent) might be possible" and it would still have the same structure. (Parentheses added for clarity.)

Comment: Actually,I agree with you. But I am still confused about another sentence which is similar to the sentence you answered:It would be an excellent experience for you to travel a little. You can't refer it to "you to travel a little". So how to understand it?

Answer (score 1):

On another forum I wrote the following on this topic. Maybe it is of help.

Hello Dave,
you have discovered that verb constructions with infinitive
have a lot of variants

1 modal verbs + inf (infinitive) - can do, must go, would know

2 verbs + to inf - have to do, plan to do

3 verb + acc (accusative) + inf - Let the children come to me.

4 verb + acc + to-inf -  He wanted me to help him

5 verb + for + acc + to inf - He arrange for her to have a bath

Larger grammars give for each type of verb construction
a selective list of verbs, an explanation of the structure
and some examples.

Verb constructions are an important sector of grammar and when you
are interested in this point of grammar you have to make your own observations and complement the different lists.

I have short notations for the vcs (verb constructions):

a stands for accusative

t for to

i for infinitive

f for for

So you have the following vcs:
ai, ati, fati

The fati-construction is not so frequent. The most common verb
+ fati is to arrange for someone to do something/to have something.

In the sector verb + acc (accusative) + verb form
there are still other constructions, for example with past participle
to have something done
or with infinitive passive
Wikipedia often has this information:
The article does not exist. But you can ask for it to be created.

Another example with fati:
He motioned for her to enter.