# The use of the preposition "for"

Tags: to-infinitive, for

**A. The point of this exercise is for you to find someone to be friends with.**

A1. What does "for you" mean here?

A2. Can you replace it with " The point of this exercise is you finding someone to be friends with"?

**B. I have always blamed myself for him leaving.**

B1. What does "for him" mean here?

B2. Can you replace it with "I have always blamed myself for his departure"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1. In that sentence "*for you*" relates to the "point".  When the exercise is completed, somebody gets a point (achieves the goal).  The goal is *given* to somebody (or the *point* is awarded) to achieve.  When we talk of gifts (or awards), we use noun-preposition-noun phrases.  "*This gift is **for** you*".

A2. You can't replace it with that sentence because it lacks the preposition that would connect the two nouns, and "**you**" cannot **be** "*the point*".

B.  First off, that sentence is not entirely grammatically correct.  It's colloquial.  The correct sentence would end "...*for **his** leaving*".

B1. The verb "*blame*" is transitive.  It can have a direct object and an indirect object.  The accepted grammatical construct is "*blame {direct obj} **for** {indirect obj}*", for instance "*blame somebody **for** something*".  The direct object is the *target* of the blame (accusation) and the indirect object is the *reason* for the blame.  In this sentence "**him leaving**" is the indirect object of the verb *blame* (and "**myself**" is the direct object).

B2. Yes, and that would actually be much more proper.

Comment: Thanks. It was a figure of speech, to deliver the point, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your rephrasings (A2 and B2) improve on the original.

In A, "for" was misused. To say "The point. of Q ...is **for** [X]"  is akin to saying "the reason is **because** [X]."  It's redundant.

The reason *is [X]* (or *is that [X]*); it is NOT *because [X]*.

Likewise, the "point" of the exercise) is not **for** [X];  the *exercise itself* is **for [X]**, thus the "point" **is** [X].

(A) should have been worded as:

- The point of the exercise is **to [help you] find** someone. . . " ( (the infinitive serves as a *noun complement*; specifically, a *predicate nominative*)

Or

- This exercise is for finding someone. . .
  ( *predicate adjective*)

Answer (score 1):

The verb construction verb + for + noun + to infinitive is a special infinitive construction of English that is typical of English and often unknown in other languages. It is used very often.

Example: I arranged for a taxi to get you to the station.

It is astonishing how many variants this construction has. Actually this construction is a larger grammar chapter, but most grammars treat this grammar point negligently.

This construction is possible after nouns, verbs, adjectives and in some other cases.

Perhaps this is helpful [Link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23018/how-to-parse-it-might-be-possible-for-a-single-woman-to-be-accepted-as-a-foster)